# Section block with allow inner blocks in block editor, WordPress 5.0.2

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am creating a custom block name section, want to make it more power full with adding settings with different css properties.

But stuck at the allowing blocks inside this custom block as column block does.

here is what I done:

```
// All blocks located here
if( !defined( 'WP_BLOCKS_URL' ) ) {
    define( 'WP_BLOCKS_URL', get_template_directory_uri() . '/blocks/' );
}

// Register Gutenberg blocks
add_action( 'init', 'wp_register_gutenberg_blocks_assets' );
function wp_register_gutenberg_blocks_assets() {

    if( ! function_exists( 'register_block_type' ) ) {
        // Gutenberg is not active.
        return;
    }

    // Register 
    register_block_type( 'custom/section', array(
        'editor_script' => 'wp-section-block-script',
    ) );
}

// Manage editor scripts
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'wp_custom_gutenberg_scripts' );
function wp_custom_gutenberg_scripts() {

    if( ! function_exists( 'register_block_type' ) ) {
        // Gutenberg is not active.
        return;
    }

    // Section block script
    wp_register_script(
        'wp-section-block-script', // Handle.
        WP_BLOCKS_URL . 'section/block.js',
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-components', 'wp-element', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-editor' ), // Dependencies, defined above.
        WP_BLOCKS_URL . 'section/block.js',
        true
    );
}


// block.js
var el = wp.element.createElement;
var registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType;
var InnerBlocks = wp.editor.InnerBlocks;
var BlockControls = wp.editor.BlockControls;

var ALLOWED_BLOCKS = ['core/paragraph'];

registerBlockType( 'custom/section', {
    title: 'Custom Section',
    description: '',
    icon: 'ANY-ICON',
    category: 'layout',
    edit: function() {

        return [
            el(BlockControls, { key: 'controls' },
                el('div', { className: 'custom-sec-inner' },
                    el(InnerBlocks, {
                        allowedBlocks: ALLOWED_BLOCKS
                    } )
                )
            ),
        ];
    },
    save: function(props) {
        return [
            el('div', { className: 'custom-sec-block' },
                el('div', { className: 'custom-sec-inner' },
                    el( InnerBlocks.Content )
                )
            ),
        ];
    }
} );
```

It does not work, event doesn't give any error and not even element is added to the gutenberg builder.

Please help with appropriate solution.

Comment: Since your element is not adding to Gutenberg builder, means there's something wrong with your assets loading.

Comment: @AshiquzzamanKiron, Thanks for the reply. It displayed to Gutenberg builder, but it is not added to the builder when we click on it. I check all scripts load there if I am missing anyone than please suggest.

Comment: Seems like you're having a compiling issue if the block is not being added to the gutenberg editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code also does not work for me, below is an example of a working code along with the function of registering blocks. One of the reasons for the error in your code is the use of `BlockControls`, but there are also errors in the block registration function.

**function.php**

After development change `$version` to a fixed number(for caching a script)

```
//Gutenberg block script rout
if( !defined( 'WP_BLOCKS_URL' ) ) {
    define( 'WP_BLOCKS_URL', get_template_directory_uri() . '/blocks/' );
}

//Register Gutenberg block
function custom_gutenberg_block() {

    if( !function_exists('register_block_type') ) return; //Gutenberg is not active

    //Script version
    $version = time(); //Сhange to a fixed number after development

    //Section block script
    wp_register_script(
        'wp-section-block-script', WP_BLOCKS_URL . 'section/block.js', array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-element', 'wp-editor' ), $version
    );

    //Register block
    register_block_type( 'custom/section', array(
        'editor_script' => 'wp-section-block-script',
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_gutenberg_block' );
```

**/blocks/section/block.js**

Need add props.className to wrapper on saved function to render saved content

```
//block.js
(function( editor, element ) {

const registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType;
const el = element.createElement;
const InnerBlocks = editor.InnerBlocks;
//const BlockControls = editor.BlockControls; //Remove or change this

const allowedBlocks = [ 'core/paragraph' ];
const icon = el('svg', { width: 24, height: 24 }, el('path', {d: "M 0.71578,2 C 0.32064,2 0,2.3157307 0,2.7060291 V 21.294175 C 0,21.683751 0.32064,22 0.71578,22 H 23.28422 C 23.67936,21.999999 24,21.68375 24,21.294174 V 5.9812162 2.7060291 C 24,2.3157307 23.67936,2 23.28422,2 Z M 1.43136,3.411854 H 22.56864 V 5.9812162 H 1.43136 Z m 15.96822,0.4609128 c -0.46106,0 -0.83495,0.3687886 -0.83495,0.8235651 0,0.4549561 0.37389,0.8237674 0.83495,0.8237674 0.46124,0 0.83494,-0.3688113 0.83494,-0.8237674 0,-0.4547765 -0.3737,-0.8235651 -0.83494,-0.8235651 z m 2.78339,0 c -0.46124,0 -0.83515,0.3687886 -0.83515,0.8235651 0,0.4549561 0.37391,0.8237674 0.83515,0.8237674 0.46106,0 0.83494,-0.3688113 0.83494,-0.8237674 0,-0.4547765 -0.37388,-0.8235651 -0.83494,-0.8235651 z M 3.65005,3.990507 c -0.39514,0 -0.71557,0.316068 -0.71557,0.7058249 0,0.3899364 0.32043,0.7060281 0.71557,0.7060281 h 8.92617 c 0.39533,0 0.71579,-0.3160917 0.71579,-0.7060281 0,-0.3897569 -0.32046,-0.7058249 -0.71579,-0.7058249 z M 1.43136,7.3930022 H 22.56864 V 20.588214 H 1.43136 Z m 7.89453,1.5110662 c -0.16452,0 -0.32898,0.05577 -0.46246,0.1672098 -0.53833,0.4497184 -4.5418,3.7936988 -5.09862,4.2587688 -0.30157,0.251951 -0.33909,0.697517 -0.0837,0.994982 0.25543,0.297464 0.70697,0.33447 1.00873,0.08252 l 0.0299,-0.02491 v 3.282584 H 3.93296 c -0.39533,0 -0.71579,0.316024 -0.71579,0.705961 0,0.389937 0.32046,0.706028 0.71579,0.706028 h 16.13408 c 0.39533,0 0.71579,-0.316091 0.71579,-0.706028 0,-0.389937 -0.32046,-0.705961 -0.71579,-0.705961 h -1.57797 v -1.656765 h 1.04279 c 0.4801,0 0.82469,-0.458384 0.68462,-0.911716 L 18.45791,9.4042733 c -0.20526,-0.6650049 -1.16379,-0.6650049 -1.36924,0 l -1.75836,5.6924727 c -0.14007,0.453151 0.20415,0.911716 0.68462,0.911716 h 1.04278 v 1.656764 h -3.1256 v -3.282584 l 0.0299,0.02491 c 0.30176,0.251951 0.7533,0.214945 1.00873,-0.08252 0.25543,-0.297465 0.21792,-0.743031 -0.0837,-0.994982 C 14.37068,12.898749 10.59208,9.7426047 9.78843,9.0712782 9.65494,8.9598418 9.49041,8.9040684 9.32589,8.9040684 Z m 0,1.6310446 3.17472,2.651678 v 4.478436 h -0.99242 v -3.38553 c 0,-0.389937 -0.32043,-0.706028 -0.71558,-0.706028 H 7.85924 c -0.39533,0 -0.71572,0.316091 -0.71572,0.706028 v 3.38553 H 6.15103 v -4.478436 h 2.1e-4 z m 8.4474,1.497088 0.79229,2.564476 h -1.58437 z m -9.19848,2.953457 h 1.50202 v 2.679569 H 8.57481 Z"}) );

registerBlockType( 'custom/section', {
    title: 'Custom Section',
    description: 'Custom Section',
    icon: icon,
    category: 'layout',
    keywords: ['custom Section'],

    //Edit
    edit: function( props ) {
        return (
            //el(BlockControls, { key: 'controls' }, //Need to remove or change this
                el('div', { className: props.className },
                    el( InnerBlocks, { allowedBlocks: allowedBlocks } )
                )
            //),
        );
    },

    //Save
    save: function( props ) {
        return (
            el('div', { className: props.className }, //Need add props.className to render saved content
                el('div', { className: 'custom-sec-inner' },
                    el( InnerBlocks.Content, null )
                )
            )
        );
    }
});

})(
    window.wp.editor,
    window.wp.element
);
```

Comment: Still not done with full, but it helps a lot. Thanks.